# Menu missing from Mobile vie

Tags: wordpress, menu

We are facing an error, where the menu is missing from mobile version of our website when we see vertically, but when we tilt the phone to horizontal view we can see the menu bar.
Can anyone help on this please.

Web: [www.jcilmglobal.info](http://www.jcilmglobal.info)

Want this problem to be solved.